# How can I use my own svg file in gitlab badges?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, badge

I have created my own svg file and pushed to my repository, when I try to use the link to that svg file as link for the badge image it does not show up the badge image properly. I am not sure how I can create an endpoint for my own svg file.

I am expecting my svg image to show up in the badge